# Who use class variables in SOAP calls with Savon?

Tags: ruby, savon

I'm writing a little client using Ruby and Savon. The interface changed significantly from version 0.7 to 0.8.x. All my calls don't work anymore :-(.
How can I pass on a local member variable.
Please see the example, @userName and @userPassword are not defined within the block.

```
begin
    @response = @authentication_svc.request :wsdl, "AuthenticateUser" do  
        http.headers["SOAPAction"] = "AuthenticateUser"  
        soap.body = "#{@userName}#{@passwd}"  
    end  
rescue Savon::SOAP::Fault => e  
    @last_soap_error = e.message  
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid having to assign everything to local variables, write methods which take objects (like soap and http) from inside the block. Because the methods belong to the class (not the instance), they can still be called from within the block, but once you are in the context of the method, your instance variables are available to you.

```
def do_request
  begin
    @response = @authentication_svc.request :wsdl, "AuthenticateUser" do  
      prepare_soap(soap,http)
    end
  rescue Savon::SOAP::Fault => e  
    @last_soap_error = e.message  
  end 
end

def prepare_soap(soap, http)
  http.headers["SOAPAction"] = "AuthenticateUser"  
  soap.body = "#{@userName}#{@passwd}"  
end
```

Answer (score 2):

After reading the changelog more carefully I understood that Savon uses instance_eval to execute the block. Therefore one cannot use instance variables of another class within that block. That's also stated in the changelog.
To solve my problem I assigned the value of the instance variable to a local variable. That did the trick for me.

Comment: Nice. That is pretty unusual behavior.

Comment: savon only uses instance_eval if you're passing a block without arguments. please take a look at [the new documentation](http://rubiii.github.com/savon/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid your question does not make much sense.

- Blocks have access to anything available outside the block.
- `@userName` and `@passwd` are instance variables, not local or class variables. Ruby doesn't have anything normally called "member variables." In any case, if they are set in the class where you are making this call, you can access them just fine within the block.

As a footnote, the convention is to use underscores and not camel case for naming variables in Ruby -- `@user_name` instead of `@userName`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Please excuse my old fashioned vocabulary and spelling.Let me rephrase my question: I cannot access instance variables inside the block I pass on to Savon::Client#request.